# Clear generated table js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I have this code and trying to create a table works fine. But every time I press the button it adds the same table below the previous one. I've tried `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = ""` at the beginning
but it gives me nothing, because no table appears. I've tried `deleteRow` loop, but no reaction. I also did it without creating new table, but then it keeps adding new rows instead of new tables. Found some other solutions but unfortunately nothing works for me.
Code gives output "[object HTMLTableElement]" in target element and create brand new table.

```
<script>
    function TableCreate() {

        var table = document.createElement('table');
        for (var i = 1; i < val.length; i++) {
            if (i % max === 1) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            }
            var td1 = document.createElement('td');
            var text1 = document.createTextNode(val[i]);
            td1.appendChild(text1);
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            if (i % 4 === 1) {
                table.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(table);
    }
</script>


<html>
<table id="target"></table> <!-- tried also with div -->
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = table;` instead of  `document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(table);`

Comment: If you want require only one table, then remove the loop from the code.

Comment: @connexo I've tried this one, zero output then

Comment: @Keshav New table appear when hit the button, loop is necesary to add col and row

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but works just fine.

```
<script>
    var table = document.createElement('table');
                for (var i = 1; i < val.length; i++) {
                    if (i % max === 1) {
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    }
                    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                    var text1 = document.createTextNode(val[i]);
                    td1.appendChild(text1);
                    tr.appendChild(td1);
                    if (i % 4 === 1) {
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("tb").remove();
                table.id = "tb";
                document.getElementById("tb").children = document.body.appendChild(table);
  </script>

<html>
    <body>
        <table id="tb"></table>
    </body>    
</html>
```